# Auto Generate Gets and Sets from a Database

Tags: .net, vb.net, code-generation, data-access

I am coming from VB6 and I am starting to convert an existing VB6 code to VB.Net. What tools can I use to automate this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a complete code generator for your data access layer and entities [LLBLGen](http://www.llblgen.com/defaultgeneric.aspx) is a good tool. If you only looking for a tool that simply generates entity classes [Wilson OR Mapper](http://www.ormapper.net/) is my favorite.

Also [CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/) and [.net Tiers Templates](http://nettiers.com/) are very powerful.

Comment: `Virus was removed on OR Mapper using FSecure` while trying to open the website..

Answer (score 2):

I would probably look into using an OR/M like nHibernate, LINQ to SQL, Entity Framework, Subsonic etc. It'll give you a lot lot more, but it's probably better than to autogenerate CRUD operations.